# MySQL count() query returns rows instead of total?

Tags: mysql, sql

What might be wrong with this query:

```
select count(customer_email) as num_prev
  from _pj_cust_email_by_date
  where order_date < '2011-02'
  and customer_email is not null
  group by customer_email having count(order_date) > 0;
```

Which returns row results such as:

```
1
2
3
2
1
5
4
```

When I'm trying to get a *full count* of how many customers in total purchased during the specified date range?

`_pj_cust_email_by_date` is a view that returns only email address and order date in YYYY-MM-DD format. I do not have access to use anything save for this view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subquery it further

```
select count(*) CustomerCount
from (
    select count(customer_email) as num_prev
    from _pj_cust_email_by_date
    where order_date < '2011-02'
    and customer_email is not null
    group by customer_email having count(order_date) > 0;
) as innercount
```

That would normally be the approach, but since you're using `having count(order_date) > 0`, I think you only need

```
select count(distinct customer_email) as num_prev
from _pj_cust_email_by_date
where order_date < '2011-02' and customer_email is not null
```

Because the HAVING clause will never detail with empty order_dates which makes the HAVING clause **a dud**, actually.

Comment: Even if this query *is* an inner-query?

Comment: @philwinkle Yes, even if. So you put one level between this and the outer.

Comment: In the subquery expression, the `COUNT(customer_email)` is redundant, as the outer query just counts the rows returned, you could just pass back `customer_email`, or even `1`.

Comment: @Orbling - you're right. And I can almost guarantee that is exactly what MySQL will do to optimize it. The first query is there to show how to subquery for a count (overall) with an embedded `HAVING` against the inner query - I concede I could have cleaned up other aspects, but the final query is the latter one.

Comment: aka cyberwiki: Yes, hopefully the engine should optimise that.  Glad you retained the subquery, as that is a more generic way of handling the `HAVING` clause with a different group to the desired result aggregation.  The final single query is peculiar to the question example.

Answer (score 3):

The `GROUP BY` is causing that.

It causes one result row to be returned per group, in this for each distinct value of `customer_email`.

If you want the total number of distinct email addresses, then you need to drop the `GROUP BY` clause and change the `COUNT` to `COUNT(DISTINCT customer_email)`.

Comment: So how, then, can I use the clause from `HAVING`... AFAIK I can't use the `count()` function in the `WHERE` clause...

Comment: It seems as though I can use HAVING without the GROUP BY clause... I'm investigating this and I'll post my findings.

Comment: @philwinkle: You need the subquery, see "Richard aka cyberkiwi"'s answer.

Comment: @philwinkle: You can use `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`, but the results will be different.  The grouping directly effects the results of any aggregate function.

Comment: You are correct - this was the cause of the actual subject of the question. I'll vote this up - but the previous answer above went a step further and helped me get what I actually needed.

Comment: @philwinkle: Aye, his answer was more conclusive, hence my referencing it. :-)